# Resizing and aligning all Charts in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to create a VBA sub to align and resize all charts within my workbook through multiple worksheets, I believe I have a general idea to the resizing but No idea how to align them to a certain column. Still fairly new to excel, here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub AllChartAlign()
    Dim works As Worksheet
    For Each works In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 2 Step 1
            With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i)
                .Height = 234
                .Width = 360
                .Left = Range("Q:Q").Left
            End With
        Next i
    Next works
End Sub
```

This works only on the active sheet, but will not loop through all the sheets.

Comment: See updated answer and comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38643389/3218398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .Left property for column alignement. If you want to align them to "C" column you could use:

```
Sub AllChartAlign()
    Dim works As Worksheet
    Dim Chrt as ChartObject
    For Each works In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To works.ChartObjects.Count
            Set Chrt = works.ChartObjects (i)
            With Chrt
                .Height = 234
                .Width = 360
                .Left = Range("C:C").Left
            End With
        Next i
    Next works
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

In case you want to align the charts top to bottom as well you may use .Top property and use the following:

```
Sub AllChartAlign()
    Dim works As Worksheet
    Dim Chrt as ChartObject
    Dim ChrtHeight As Double

    ChrtHeight = 234
    For Each works In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To works.ChartObjects.Count
            Set Chrt = works.ChartObjects (i)
            With Chrt
                .Height = ChrtHeight
                .Width = 360
                .Top = ChrtHeight * (i - 1)
                .Left = Range("C:C").Left
            End With
        Next i
    Next works
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

(Code should work now for any number of charts in a worksheet instead of considering that there is always 2 charts)

Comment: Sorry I didn't look to the loop through worksheets. You need to change 'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i)' to 'works.ChartObjects (i)'. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, additionally could i set it so that each chart doesnt overlap if I wanted to set them to the align top to the very top? As I realized that the charts are positioned fairly randomly. Would a For loop, where I add to the top align row work?

Comment: Top alignement works the same way with .Top property.

Comment: Getting an error with "Set Chrt=works.ChartObjects(i)" as a 1004 error, method failed.

Comment: That looks like there is not such chart. Replace 'For i = 1 to 2 Step 1' by 'For i =1 to works.ChartObjects.Count'